# Seperate Menu Item in bootstrap navbar and centered them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create button like menu using navbar. I want to do this because it's collapsible interface for small devices.

I write this HTML markup:

```
<div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar" style="background-color: transparent;">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar" style="background-color: black;">
                    <span class="icon-bar" style="background-color: white;"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar" style="background-color: white;"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar" style="background-color: white;"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Page 4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

and this styles:

```
nav ul {
        width: 100%;
        text-align:center;
    }

        nav ul li {
            text-align: center;
            width: 17%;
            background-color: #dbd9d9;
            margin: 10px;
        }
```

but there is some problem:

1. this menu items isn't center in `ul`. How I can center all `li` in `ul`?
2. If I resize the window in some width this menu broke in 2 line. How I can fix this that my menu being 1 line for md an lg sizes?
   [image]

[Demo](http://www.bootply.com/bty9g1xbhK)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `white-space: no-wrap` will stop items wrapping within the `ul`

Bootstrap puts `float: left` on `nav.li` elements which we need to override

Change your css to this:

```
nav ul {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  white-space:nowrap /* <-- changed */
}

nav ul li {
  text-align: center;
  width: 17%;
  background-color: #dbd9d9;
  /*padding: 10px;*/
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block !important; /* <-- changed */
  float: none !important; /* <-- changed */
}
```

Have to use `!important` to override bootstrap

[Updated bootply](http://www.bootply.com/fIEeZgN7ti)

Comment: Thanks your sample code navbar is center but when I resize the window, collapsed navbar just visible in certain width and when I resize it to smaller size it will disappeared. How I can do solve this issue?

Comment: You mean the hamburger menu shows? that is by design with bootstrap - if this helps, please accept the answer

Comment: your samlpe works fine in md and lg screens but not in sm and xs screens

Answer (score 2):

With Changes in your HTML and `removing width of li`, I got this working as you wanted.

```
 <ul class="row nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active col-xs-3 col-sm-2 col-ms-2 col-lg-2"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li class="col-xs-3 col-sm-2 col-ms-2 col-lg-2"><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
      <li class="col-xs-3 col-sm-2 col-ms-2 col-lg-2"><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
      <li class="col-xs-3 col-sm-2 col-ms-2 col-lg-2"><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
      <li class="col-xs-3 col-sm-2 col-ms-2 col-lg-2"><a href="#">Page 4</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Here is a [working Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/qZ7Ec9rArA)

Dont worry about setting the width to the `li` manually, use the bootstrap inbuilt classes. Also the above HTML could be rewritten like below.

```
<li class="col-xs-3 col-sm-2"><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
```

You dont have to specify `col-ms-2 col-lg-2` because by default bootstrap framwework will carry forward styles to all the devices untill a specific rule for that device is given. Here the rule `col-sm-2` will be carried out to md device and lg device. But its always good practice to be as detailed as possible.

Comment: The `li` are not centered in the `ul` - point 1. in the question

Comment: Yes I got you.. I deleted my comment after I understood what you were pointing at. At first it looked like it was centered. But when carefully inspecting in developer window it is not.. thanks for pointing this.

Comment: @Kerezo do you want navbat to be center of its container?? or you want the li's to be in center of ul?

Comment: @Reddy I want both of them